# quit() function not working in Canopy, but works using terminal

Tags: enthought, canopy

I'm learning python online at the moment and using the (macOS) Canopy install of python. The lesson was how to use the quit() function with a try except. I get this error in Canopy:

```
---> 11     quit()
     13 print 'Your number is:', number
NameError: name 'quit' is not defined
```

----------------- here is the code:

```
try:
    inpt = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
    number = float(inpt)
except:
    print 'Error, please enter a numeric number'
    quit()
print 'Your number is:', number
```

All the code does is print out your number but if you put something in that's not a number, it says 'Error, please enter a numeric number', instead of throwing an error.

Same code works fine using terminal. Now I'm wondering, should I be using Canopy or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Canopy's Python shell is IPython's QtConsole. IPython has taken the scientific Python world by storm in recent years for its power and convenience, and in most respects it is a proper superset of standard Python, but a few of its small convenience changes can be confusing for beginners. `quit` is one of those small changes. (A more commonly confusing one is described at https://support.enthought.com/entries/25750190-Modules-are-already-available-in-the-pylab-python-prompt-but-not-in-a-script).

For this exercise, I would suggest simply replacing `quit()` with the equivalent `import sys;sys.exit()`